# "PROJECT" statement in sql database simulator (sqlfiddle) not working

Tags: mysql, sqlfiddle

Link to simulator:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcb16/1

I've been trying out SQL fiddle and used the sample fiddle with MySQL, and the 'project' statement is not recognized... what is used instead of `PROJECT` or what am I doing wrong?

It seems like

```
JOIN
```

works, though...

Comment: The SQL Fiddle page you have linked to does not contain the word PROJECT anywhere. When asking questions it is best to put the actual code (SQL in this case) instead of linking to a fiddle page. That way it doesn't change when you fiddle with your fiddle. :-)

Comment: Ok, I mean when you type PROJECT in, it won't recognize it, and I am pretty sure this is a sql command, because it uses it as sql code in my published database book

Comment: Perhaps you could link to some documentation somewhere that has `PROJECT` as valid SQL syntax. PROJECT is a Relational Algebra operation, not SQL. [This page](https://mivuletech.wordpress.com/2011/03/22/an-overview-of-relational-algebra-operators-and-their-sql-translations/) talks about how the PROJECT operation is translated as a `SELECT` statement in SQL. There is no (standard) `PROJECT` SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Project is not a statement. 
It is operation performed by the select statement.

I think you want to use JOIN as per your explanation.

So basically **JOIN** clause is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a common field between them